# Jmeter Configuration for Web App

Tags: java, jmeter

I have downloaded Jmeter files and ran batch file to open up GUI. I have given HTTP Request defaults with Web Application's **Port** and **IP** and have added *HTTP Cookie Manager*, *View Results in Table* and *HTTP Request*(Path as /).

When i run it against 50 Users, i m getting some Results. My question is, How to Login to Web App and Perform basic CRUD operations and check Web App's behavior. What's actually happening currently? What are the obtained results conveying?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what exactly you want to know, so someone will be able to write an answer.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel - I have added 50 Users, Given Port and IP of Web App Server. When i run the Thread, Whats happening actually? What obtained results convey and how to analyze the Web App's behaviour using this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/), to wit:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.htmlhttp://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

In general load testing using JMeter needs to be done as follows:

1. Record your test scenario(s) using [JMeter' s Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. Verify if the script runs with 1 users using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
3. Perform correlation, fixes and parametrisation if needed.
4. Add virtual users, iterations, set ramp-up and ramp-down times according to your test plan
5. Run the test
6. Use [JMeter Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) to analyse results. You can also use custom listeners available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project or online tools like [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/) or [JAnalyser.com](http://janalyser.com/)

Also I believe [The Ultimate JMeter Resource List](https://blazemeter.com/blog/ultimate-jmeter-resource-list) will be useful at any stage.

Comment: Thnx for the detailed info. I m trying this. Got this error when pushed Start button of HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - "could not create script recorder-port in use. Choose another port.: Address already in use: JVM_Bind". What is this error?

Comment: I got it corrected(Configured different Port). As per the document, it says after click of start button, file called "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt" will be created. But i m not getting any such files in bin folder. Did i go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Try searching the whole disk/partition. If you run JMeter from shortcut or symlink log file and certificate may go to the other location

Comment: Thank You. I was able to Record properly. When i play back scripts, Jquery connections are refused. saying "Connection to http://code.jquery.com:xxxxx refused". and for Ajax calls, getting 404. What is the cause?

Comment: You ain't gonna need connections to code.jquery.com as 1) JMeter cannot execute JavaScript 2) it is external domain which needs to be filtered out as you should focus solely on your application and exclude external resources. See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1903905-excluding-domains-from-the-load-test) article for detailed explanation

Comment: I have removed recorded elements for which all connection was refused and running tests. Results obtained are proper ones right? i mean, this is the proper configuration for running Load Testing right?

Comment: and Is there a effect on Load Testing results for GUI and GUI-less Jmeter run?

Comment: From application under test point of view - no difference, but JMeter in GUI mode consumes much more resources on load generator side hence results may not be reliable

Comment: Our webapp page needs unique 10 digit number to be entered while submitting a form. How this can be achieved(i have recorded scripts, how to pass these values to parameters)?  and Is it possible to record in multiple record controllers in the same test plan so that i can get results of each record controller and should be executed from top to bottom approach(concurrently)?

Comment: Out of scope, ask another question.